# iOS: How do i prevent temporary files Visibility

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

i am working on a app that generates temporary video from the still image. But i don't want the user to view the temporary file what i have generated. But the moment when the app is generating the video file,the video is listing out by the camera roll.

my Question is How can i generate the temporary media file that could't have access to '**camera roll,iTunes and iCloud**'?

please help me. thanks in advance.

Code:

```
[assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^
     { 
         NSURL *url = _outMovieURL; ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
         [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url 
                                     completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) 
                                     { 
                                         NSLog(@"Done!"); 
                                     }]; 
     }];
```

Comment: What directory are you writing to? If you write to the camera roll then that it where it will be. If you write to a temp directory you won't have that problem.

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFirstDownloadmp4.mp4"];

Comment: i am using the above code to create the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block:

```
 [assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^
 { 
     NSURL *url = _outMovieURL; ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
     [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url 
                                 completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) 
                                 { 
                                     NSLog(@"Done!"); 
                                 }]; 
 }];
```

Is to write file in camera roll. So don't use this while you have only created temporary video. Write that temporary video file in `documentDirectory` instead, (or probably it's already in `documentDirectory`, while you are creating it, all you need to do is to not write that file in camera roll with this code).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSTemporaryDirectory()` and append your own affix at the end for any temporary files. Files in that directory will be cleaned by the OS or you can delete right after you are done with it.

Comment: path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%llu.mov", NSTemporaryDirectory(), mach_absolute_time()];  I have tried with this but the video visible in camera roll

Comment: @user1713827 that is highly unlikely, can you post the code where you actually use the path that was generated? or have you installed any jailbroken tweak that might change camera roll's behavior?

Comment: `[assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
        
        NSURL *url = _outMovieURL;
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                        
                                        NSLog(@"Done!");
                                    }];
    }];`

Comment: @user1713827 I am assuming you are initializing the AVAssetWriter with the _outMovieURL right? If you don't use ALAssetsLibrary call in the completion block, nothing will end up in the camera roll. Or your problem is that video appear as soon as you start creating, not after you are all done?